# Apache2 isolate virtualhosts

Tags: apache2

I'd like to isolate each "www subdirectory" so mysite1.ext can't access to mysite2.ext files, is this possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you Must conf You virtualHost Apache for this

like This

```
 <VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
       ServeName www.example.com
       DocumentRoot /path/to/your/virtualroot
       ...
       ... usual stuff ...
       ...
        php_admin_value open_basedir /path/to/your/virtualroot:/some/other/path
 </VirtualHost>
```

Last Line Is For Isolate PHP To Access Other Directory

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want in Apache you would use Name Based VirtualHosts. This allows you to configure two or more separate Web server environments on one IP address. It would look something like this.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.mysite1.ext
ServerAlias domain.ext *.domain.ext
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.mysite2.ext
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

You can read more about this configuration [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) This would all go in Sites.enabled or http.conf depending on your end stage configuration.